# Displaying Message based on different checkbox combinations

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

We have a series of 10 check boxes. We are attempting to get a message to display depending on the series of check boxes selected. However, our problem is that upon pressing the button it shows all of the possible combinations.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If CheckBox1.Checked = True And CheckBox6.Checked = True Then MessageBox.Show("On Campus Student Center")
        If CheckBox1.Checked = True And CheckBox7.Checked = True Then MessageBox.Show("On Campus Marketplace")
        If CheckBox1.Checked = True And CheckBox8.Checked = True Then MessageBox.Show("Around Campus")
        If CheckBox2.Checked = True And CheckBox3.Checked = True And CheckBox9.Checked = True Then MessageBox.Show("2 Mile Restaurant")
        If CheckBox2.Checked = True And CheckBox3.Checked = True And CheckBox10.Checked = True Then MessageBox.Show("2 Mile FF")
        If CheckBox2.Checked = True And CheckBox4.Checked = True And CheckBox9.Checked = True Then MessageBox.Show("3 Mile Restaurant")
        If CheckBox2.Checked = True And CheckBox4.Checked = True And CheckBox10.Checked = True Then MessageBox.Show("3 Mile FF")
        If CheckBox2.Checked = True And CheckBox5.Checked = True And CheckBox9.Checked = True Then MessageBox.Show("4 Mile Restaurant")
        If CheckBox2.Checked = True And CheckBox5.Checked = True And CheckBox10.Checked = True Then MessageBox.Show("4 Mile FF")
        If CheckBox1.Checked = True And CheckBox6.Checked = True And CheckBox7.Checked = True And CheckBox8.Checked = True Then MessageBox.Show("All On Campus")
        If CheckBox1.Checked = True And CheckBox6.Checked = True And CheckBox7.Checked = True Then MessageBox.Show("Student Center and Marketplace")
        If CheckBox1.Checked = True And CheckBox6.Checked = True And CheckBox8.Checked = True Then MessageBox.Show("Student Center and Around Campus")
        If CheckBox1.Checked = True And CheckBox8.Checked = True And CheckBox7.Checked = True Then MessageBox.Show("Market Place and around")
    End Sub
End Class
```

For example if we follow the checkbox selection of the last statement. Check boxes 1,7, and 8. We get the following message boxes:

- "On Campus Market Place"
- "Around Campus"
- "Marketplace and around"

Where as we only want it to show text for the final if statement and not all of the coded combinations within that series of checkbox selection.

Comment: I would recommend using ````AndAlso```` instead of ````And```` as you don't care if the other statements are true if the first statement is false. Also, you just need to evaluate ````CheckBox.Checked```` as that returns a Boolean, so no need to have the ````= True```` part on there.  If it is checked, then it will return true.

Comment: The code is not easy to follow either, so I would recommend breaking it up. It appears the first logic is based on CheckBox1 and CheckBox2, so have those in their own IF statements.  And in those statements, you can break it up some.  That will help you debug the issue.

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: I edited and formatted awhile ago, but it's been waiting to be peer-reviewed before it will update. It bugged me, too.

Answer (score 3):

You could easily setup all of your potential combinations in a Dictionary(Of CheckBox(), String), this would help manage them too because it looks like you have a duplicate (CheckBox 1, 6, and 7). The key would represent all of the checkbox controls that would need to be checked and the value would be your message.

Then in your button click event, you'd get every item in the Dictionary where all of the Checkbox controls in the key are checked. Then you'd order the collection by the length of the key and get the first message:

```
Private ReadOnly combinations As Dictionary(Of CheckBox(), String) = New Dictionary(Of CheckBox(), String)() From {
    { {CheckBox1, CheckBox6}, "On Campus Student Center" },
    { {CheckBox1, CheckBox7}, "On Campus Market Place" },
    { {CheckBox1, CheckBox8}, "Around Campus " },
    { {CheckBox2, CheckBox3, CheckBox9}, "2 Mile Restaurant" },
    { {CheckBox2, CheckBox3, CheckBox10}, "2 Mile FF" },
    { {CheckBox2, CheckBox4, CheckBox9}, "3 Mile Restaurant" },
    { {CheckBox2, CheckBox4, CheckBox10}, "3 Mile FF" },
    { {CheckBox2, CheckBox5, CheckBox9}, "4 Mile Restaurant" },
    { {CheckBox2, CheckBox5, CheckBox10}, "4 Mile FF" },
    { {CheckBox1, CheckBox6, CheckBox7}, "All On Campus " },
    { {CheckBox1, CheckBox6, CheckBox7}, "Student Center and Marketplace " },
    { {CheckBox1, CheckBox6, CheckBox8}, "Student Center and Around Campus" },
    { {CheckBox1, CheckBox8, CheckBox7}, "Marketplace and Around" }
}

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim matchedCombinations = combinations.Where(Function(kvp) kvp.Key.All(Function(cb) cb.Checked))

    If (matchedCombinations.Any()) Then
        Dim bestMatch = matchedCombinations.OrderByDescending(Function(kvp) kvp.Key.Length).First()

        MessageBox.Show(bestMatch.Value, "Valid Combination", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("None of the checked CheckBoxes matched a specified combination", "Invalid Combo", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Elegant solution, and no spaghetti logic that comes with nested If statements. +1

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use LINQ like the other answer, here is a more simplistic answer.  From a performance standpoint, they are basically equal as you aren't really iterating through a lot of objects.  It's basically a matter of preference.

HTML

```
<div>

            <input type="checkbox" id="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
            <input type="checkbox" id="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
            <input type="checkbox" id="CheckBox3" runat="server" />
            <input type="checkbox" id="CheckBox4" runat="server" />
            <input type="checkbox" id="CheckBox5" runat="server" />
            <input type="checkbox" id="CheckBox6" runat="server" />
            <input type="checkbox" id="CheckBox7" runat="server" />
            <input type="checkbox" id="CheckBox8" runat="server" />

            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Process" />

        </div>
```

Code-Behind

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        If CheckBox1.Checked Then

            If CheckBox6.Checked Then
                MessageBox.Show("On Campus Student Center")

            ElseIf CheckBox7.Checked Then
                MessageBox.Show("On Campus Marketplace")

            End If

        ElseIf CheckBox2.Checked Then

            If CheckBox6.Checked Then
                ' message
            ElseIf CheckBox7.Checked Then
                ' message
            End If

        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: The beauty of the other answer is that it is highly configurable. You can [almost] change the behavior of the program by modifying data, rather than modifying source code [with some minor changes].